# Is there a way to have zero touch install for MS teams connectors into channel?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

Looking for a way to automate webhooks creation (i.e. add connectors) for shared & private teams.

Is it possible?

Best Boris

I was expected to have graph api call to install connectors in the same way as it's done for apps.

Answer (score 0):

Currently we cannot create/configure incoming webhook programmatically. There is no Graph API available to create incoming webhook. This is by design.

Also please note that connectors are not supported in shared channels - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/limits-specifications-teams#limits-for-shared-channels.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Meghana, bot cant work with private channels too, is there any solution that can allow application to interact with private channels users?

Comment: Engineering team is working to support bots as well, currently there is no workaround for this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8vH2.png

Comment: Thanks. Is there a specific  timeline for having it on?

Comment: No, we do not have any timelines. The doc will be updated whenever its supported.